# Why sign-in message not appears for connecting to Azure AD while doing intune device enrollment?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10, intune

I was enrolling an Windows IoT Core device(raspberry pi 3) into Intune as per below article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/intunedeviceenrollment. But when I reached to seventh step.As mentioned  I tried to get bulk token but It was not asking for sing to connecting to Azure AD.I moved forward and completed all the steps but device is not listed in enrollment device list.I assume that because it had not been asking for sing in due to this reason  device is not appear in the list.

Comment: Could you please make sure if your PC has been logged in Azure AD? I have tested that, it was asking for sign to connect to Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks Azure AD log in screen is appeared after removed all the saved credentials now and I am able to move forward.But still raspberry pi device is not listed on the Azure Portal.I am not able to identified what is issue.When I ask to Microsoft support team they refuse to provide assistance to Windows Iot Core.They only provide support for Windows Iot enterprise.That is sound strange